# Browser compatibility of angular.js and angular-ui bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, cross-browser, angular-ui, compatibility, angular-ui-bootstrap

I trying to decide whether I could to use angular.js (and [anguar-ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)) in my project.

The web application **should work** with any [reasonably modern browser](http://browsehappy.com), I was quite surprised that the right on the [angular-ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) site, after clicking on *"create a build"* button the server responds:

> Your current browser doesn't support creating custom builds. Please
>   take a second to [upgrade to a more modern browser](http://browsehappy.com) (other than Safari).

with a link to http://browsehappy.com, where my Safari (v.8) is listed, but the angular-ui-bootstrap explicitly excludes it.

In the FAQ for the angular.js is:

> AngularJS is 100% JavaScript, 100% client-side **and compatible with
>   both desktop and mobile browsers**.

also the bootstrap 3 itself is compatible too.

Since I am a complete novice to angular.js, just downloaded and trying to learn it, **but honestly, I do not want to waste several days/weeks with learning to discover: it doesn't supports Safari fully**. The support of [all reasonably modern browsers](http://browsehappy.com) is crucial for the project.

Therefore the questions are:

- Supports **angular-ui-boostrap** any reasonable modern browser **fully**, e.g. for **any** functionality?
- If not fully, which functions / modules / parts are "problematic"?
- e.g. the "build-problem" is the angular.js's *"feature"* ?

Comment: It is impossible answer anything about the "whims" - edited the question to be fully answerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The angular-ui-bootstrap build modal window kicks off a function called `isOldBrowser`. Looking through their repo you can find that function under [misc/demo/assets/app.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/431b9c76b05f2bab693e05b60d3c50b51a1459ee/misc/demo/assets/app.js#L267). Instead of looking for specific browsers it's looking for the browser to be able to execute specific functions or return certain results. Presumably, the checks would be a very generalized way for them to make sure you have an appropriate browser.

Having said that, [Bootstrap lists pretty much every browser as being supported](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support) with only a few exceptions (like Safari on Windows) plus a [couple of bugs each](http://getbootstrap.com/browser-bugs/). Angular has a [similar statement](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#what-browsers-does-angular-work-with-) in that they support all current browsers (IE9 and up). Either way you should be safe using any modern browser.